# Cannot read property 'posts' of null error marked in the code

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, null, mongoose-schema, object-reference

The code is throwing an error on the line `foundUser.posts.push(post)`

```js
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    name:String,
    posts:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"post"
        }
    ]
});

User.findOne({name:"Karikey Sharma"},function(err,foundUser){
  if(err){
    
  }else{
    foundUser.posts.push(post); // this line shows error saying cannot read posts 
    foundUser.save(function(err,data){
      if(err){
        
      }else{
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using populate you need to have Post schema too.

```
    var postSchema=new mongoose.Schema({ text:String,
    ....
    user:{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"user" } });
```

and when you try to get any item in user schema if you want to get posts too you need to use populate() like this.

```
User.findOne({name:"Karikey Sharma"}).populate('post').exec((err,user)=>{
if(err || !user){
 return;
}
else{
user.posts.push(post.id);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is returning `null`, i.e. no `User` was found with the query that you gave (`{name:"Karikey Sharma"}`).
Which means that `foundUser` is being set to `null` and trying to access `foundUser.posts` means doing `null.posts`, which will throw an error, since `null` doesn't have any property like `posts`.

You can try this instead,

```js
User.findOne({name:"Karikey Sharma"},function(err,foundUser){
  if(err || foundUser === null){ // Check if there was an error, or no user was found
    
  }else{
    foundUser.posts.push(post);
    foundUser.save(function(err,data){
```